# Right align two Divs having one absolute position

Tags: html, css

How to right align the Anchor and Content DIVs?

(The divs are Anchor and Window having blue and red border on the example)

```css
div.tabs {
      background-color: #a0a0a0;
      position: relative;
      width: 400px;
    }
      
    div.tabs ul.tabs {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    div.tabs ul.tabs li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    div.tabs div.content {
      background-color: #e8e8e8;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    div.tabs div.toolbar {
      background-color: #e8e8e8;
      position: absolute; 
      right: 12px; 
      top: 0;
    }
    
    div.popup {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    div.popup div.anchor {
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    div.popup div.window {
      border: 1px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2000;
      width: 160px;
    }
    
    p {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="tab">Tab 2</li>
      </ul>
    
      <div class="content">
        Content
      </div>
      
      <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="popup">
          <div class="anchor">
            <a>Anchor</a>    
          </div>
          <div class="window">
            <p>Line 1</p>
            <p>Line 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: please show with picture you what the want.

Comment: Right align how? ... if you set `right: 0;` to both your absolute positioned element they will _right align_ in their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to move them to the right of the tabs table. So I did just that:

In the CSS, use the following:

```
       div.tabs {
          background-color: #a0a0a0;
          position: relative;
          width: 400px;
        }

        div.tabs ul.tabs {
          list-style: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        div.tabs ul.tabs li {
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 8px;
        }

        div.tabs div.content {
          background-color: #e8e8e8;
          padding: 8px;
        }

        div.tabs div.toolbar {
          background-color: #e8e8e8;
          position: absolute; 
          right: 0px; 
          top: 0;
        }

        div.popup {
          position: relative;
        }

        div.popup div.anchor {
          border: 1px solid blue;
          position: relative;
        }

        div.popup div.window {
          border: 1px solid red;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 2000;
          width: 160px;
          height: 34px;
          right: 0px;
          top: 165%;
        }

        p {margin: 0;}
```

EDIT: The final version. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property `text-align: right;` within `div.popup div.anchor` and `div.popup div.window` CSS sections.

Comment: Don't circumvent the need to have some code within the question to also allow linking to jsfiddle by format it as code. Also, text should be seen as text and code as  code, hence the two formatting types.

Comment: I now edited how it should look like, so one can see what is what. Please use that type of formatting in your future answers.